# Java reading from Table

Tags: java

I have a problem with method which should use a code, search the table for the code, and then return me data with that code index; This is what I use now. The Eclipse is telling me that result may not be initialised. But I don't see another way to do this.

```
public String getService(String serviceCode){
    String result;
    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            if(serviceCode==data[i][j]){
                result =  data[i][j+1].toString() + data[i][j+2].toString();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `serviceCode==data[i][j]` [:_(](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) Click on the crying face.

Comment: What happens if `data.length` is `0`? you would never enter the loop and your result would remain `null`! Same case if the program doesn't enter the following loops. So either use `String result = new String();` or simply `String result = ""`.

Answer (score 2):

> The Eclipse is telling me that result may not be initialised

That's true:

```
public String getService(String serviceCode){
    String result; // <--
    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            if(serviceCode==data[i][j]){
                result =  data[i][j+1].toString() + data[i][j+2].toString();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If your loops don't get executed, then result will be not initialized.

Change it to

```
String result = null;
```

---

As a side note, you shouldn't use `==` to compare strings, you should use `.equals`:

```
 if(serviceCode.equals(data[i][j]))
```

Comment: Even if the loop gets executed `result` will be `null`. He's comparing references with `==` (Which probably will be always `false`).

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun Yes, but he's asking why he gets "result may not be initialised", and that's why. And I added a note about string comparison

Answer (score 1):

You are using `==` on strings, which compares references, not actual equality. Always use `string.equals(otherstring)` instead.

As for your problem, `String result;` is never initialised to `null`. If you declared it as a field, it would automatically have been assigned the value `null`, but inside the scope of a method it is undetermined. The data is whatever junk bytes happened to still be there.

So do `String result = null;`.

Comment: That's not the problem here.

Comment: How are you not getting `IndexOutOfBounds` when `j = 1` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if `data.length` is equal to 0 then you won't get any result - you have to think functionally what your method should do in such situation - maybe `IllegalStateException` will work for you?